# Set parameters of Facebook Like plugin to send and share customized data

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, customization, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

I've implemented a Facebook Like plugin on a XHTML website (can't update the doctype to html5).
Say each "post" have a Like button.

I want to create a page with a selection of "posts" and each one will have a Like button.

**2 questions:**

- **Is it possible to share the information of a post when a user clic on a like in this page?**
  Obviously, I can't use the open graph meta data because it's page related, not post related. 
  I would like the title, the photo and a short description shared on the facebook user account.
- **Is it possible to know/retrieve the list of Facebook users who "liked" a particular "post"?**
  Edit: The answer is no.

Thank you for your answers or advices !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the question is how to add like button for individual articles into a page which has a list of multiple articles.

Use the URL of the individual blog entry in the Like button code. For example if using HTML5 version of Like button then something like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/blog/1" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/blog/2" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Or if using XFMBL version then:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/blog/1" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/blog/2" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it is not what I'm looking for. I've edited my question... hope it's more clear / understandable.

Comment: Well, I wasn't clear enough in my question, but in fact you're right. I've change my mind and my app. :-)